# Different results between JS encodeURI() and PHP urldecode()

Tags: php, javascript, database, url

This is the original string

```
Apple iPad 2 16GB Wifi + 3G (AT&T)
```

after js encodeURI()

```
Apple%20iPad%202%2016GB%20Wifi%20+%203G%20(AT&T)
```

after PHP urldecode(), via $_GET from AJAX call

```
Apple iPad 2 16GB Wifi   3G (AT&T)
```

after inserting into MySQL DB wrapped with single quotes

```
Apple iPad 2 16GB Wifi   3G (AT
```

How do I get the original string exactly into database?

Comment: If the data is valid right before inserting it into MySQL, the issue can't have anything to do with URL encoding. Additionaly, how are you passing the GET argument that you need to *decode* from PHP? Decoding is automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use encodeURIComponent instead of encodeURI.

Then the string will be `Apple%20iPad%202%2016GB%20Wifi%20%2B%203G%20(AT%26T)` after encodeURIComponent in JavaScript, which will be converted back to `Apple iPad 2 16GB Wifi + 3G (AT&T)` with urldecode in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You database field is most probably not long enough to contain the full string.

Also you should encode the string with `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`

Answer (score 0):

Look up [PHP.JS's urlencode function](http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode:573) - it behaves in the exact same way as PHP's urlencode, so urldecode will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

rawurlencode in PHP will preserve the "+". Not sure about the ampersand, you could try passing the string to htmlentities.